# How can I retrieve Picklist values of standard field? package.xml not working

Tags: salesforce

I want to retrieve picklist values of status in *Fulfillment Order* Object which is a standard Object in OMS.

Here is my package.xml that I have tried,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
    <members>CaseOrigin</members>
    <members>CaseReason</members>
    <members>CaseStatus</members>
    <members>CaseType</members>
    <members>ReturnOrderStatus</members>
    <members>OrderSummaryStatus</members>
    <members>FulfillmentOrderStatus</members>
    <name>StandardValueSet</name>
    </types>
    <version>58.0</version>
</Package>
```

I'm able to retrieve values of other fields in a similar way but can't do the same for Fulfillment Order Object.

Update: As suggested in the answer it worked after using `FulfillmentOrder` rather than what I was trying to use (FulfillmentOrderStatus and also tried FulfillmentOrder.Status). I was using Field Name rather than using Standard Value Set name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm says it should be `FulfillmentStatus`, without `Order`.